# Integrating Factors Found by Inspection

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can anybody help me solve this differential equation? $y(x^2y^2-m)dx+x(x^2y^2+n)dy=0$, when I solve this by inspection, I got stuck with this equation: $(xy)^2d(xy)+nxdy-mydx=0$. Am I on the right track? or did I mess up something? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this $\displaystyle\frac{1}{xy}$.

Comment: ok, I'll try that. thanks, man

Comment: I'm still stuck, man.. is n and m constants? @Troy Woo

Comment: @Dan I suppose? Do you really understand what is an integrating factor?

Comment: oh.. I got it now. sorry, man I was confused earlier. Thanks by the way